# Apple Mapkit: Map doesn't start with my given coordinates

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm trying to open the map with a given set of co ordinates. It isn't working. It works only if I exit the view and enter it again.

Here is my code -

mapViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface mapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

mapViewController.m

```
#import "mapViewController.h"

@interface mapViewController ()

@end

@implementation mapViewController
@synthesize mapView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 39.281516;
    zoomLocation.longitude= -76.580806;

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}


@end
```

Comment: What happens if you set `animated:NO` in the last line of `viewDidLoad`? If that doesn't work, you might try moving your code to zoom the map to `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: :) I added the code to viewDidAppear and BANG! it worked, thanks!

Comment: @JakeSpencer You might want to add this as the answer. Why did it work with viewDidAppear?

Comment: Glad it worked! I have been frustrated by similar problems in the past. I am sure others could provide a better explanation of exactly what the problem is than I can but I took a stab at an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I have found that methods that animate the screen do not work as expected when running at the same time as view controller transitions. Try moving the code to zoom the map to `viewDidAppear`.